# Python Request Post issue

Tags: python, python-requests

I am working with an API that has no documentation and I have hit a stumbling block. I have a function:

```
def add_to_publicaster(self):
    # function that is called in the background whenever a user signs the petition and opts in to the mailing list
    # Makes an API call to publicaster <--- More documentation to follow --->
    username = app.config['PUBLICASTER_USERID']
    userPass = app.config['PUBLICASTER_PASS']
    headers = {'Authorization': {username:userPass}, "Content-type" : "application/json", "Accept":'text/plain'}
    url = 'https://api7.publicaster.com/Rest/Subscribers.svc/1?format=json'
    data = {"Item": {
        "Email": "juliangindi@gmail.com"
        }
    }
    r = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = data)
```

That is simply suppose to make a POST request with this format:

```
POST https://api7.publicaster.com/Rest/Subscribers.svc/1?format=json HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: <AccountID>:<Password>
Host: api7.publicaster.com
Content-Length: 64
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
 { "Item" : {
  "Email" : mkucera@whatcounts.com
 }
}
```

The code in the function, however, is not producing the desired request. Any advice would be super helpful.

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: A very long error message that basically says the server encountered an error processing the request. The solution, I think, is to match the "sample" request as closely as possible.

Comment: you have to json encode your data .. `json.dumps(dict(data=data))`

Answer (score 0):

Your headers and URL suggest you wanted to post JSON data. Encode your python structure to JSON using the `json` library:

```
import json

# ...

data = {"Item": {
    "Email": "juliangindi@gmail.com"
    }
}
r = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = json.dumps(data))
```

JSON may *look* a lot like Python, but it is really a limited form of JavaScript source code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried this before and am still getting an error. Due to the undocumented nature of the API, I might just need to keep experimenting.

Comment: @JulianGindi: What *you* tried would not work *at all*. There may be problems with the exact payload, but if your headers state you are posting `application/json` data, then at least encode the data as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You're not performing authentication correctly. Your function should look like:

```
def add_to_publicaster(self):
    # function that is called in the background whenever a user signs the petition and opts in to the mailing list
    # Makes an API call to publicaster <--- More documentation to follow --->
    username = app.config['PUBLICASTER_USERID']
    userPass = app.config['PUBLICASTER_PASS']
    headers = {"Content-type" : "application/json", "Accept":'text/plain'}
    url = 'https://api7.publicaster.com/Rest/Subscribers.svc/1?format=json'
    data = {"Item": {
        "Email": "juliangindi@gmail.com"
        }
    }
    r = requests.post(url, auth=(username, userPass), headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```